# Can we have meta tags for chatrooms?

Tags: feature-request, tags, chat

We can add tags to our chatroom which is great. What isn't great is that we have no way to indicate that we mean the tags from the meta site.

I'm one of the room owners of the [SO Close voters room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and the room is about handling the close vote queue. For that reason the room regulars really wanted to have the meta tags: [vote-to-close] and [review] to be under the room description.

After some [experiments](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19497819#19497819) we learned that the [review](/questions/tagged/review) works in the chat message posted but doesn't under the room description.

[image: tags under room description]

Can we have some basic handling of meta-tags in the tags of a chatroom?

Comment: Do you mean in the style that chat.mse has it as an easter egg?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Meta SE is one big easter egg ...

Comment: Oh, just thinking a screenshot/ mockup might be nice