# Reference tag of any site in chat

Tags: feature-request, tags, chat

Right now, in chat, we can use `[tag:tagname]` and `[meta-tag:tagname]`. But in MSE chat, I think it would be useful to reference a tag on any site through this format. For example:

```
[tag-stackoverflow.com:tagname]
```

or

```
[tag-meta.stackexchange.com:tagname]
```

Is this <strike>possible</strike> reasonably doable? Since they only render as a link (it doesn't fetch number of tagged questions or any other data), I don't imagine it would be difficult.

**EDIT:** Building upon [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242307/202832), I think the proposed markup should be valid in descriptions as well.

Comment: Would be nice to have, related feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92834/allow-tagtag-name-syntax-to-link-to-any-site (not for chat only)

Comment: Can we use meta-tag? If so,  shouldn't [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242307/can-we-have-meta-tags-for-chatrooms) be  [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @rene [It works in messages](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20289309#20289309), but I don't know if `meta-tag` works in the description.

Comment: Ok, when your request gets implemented mine can be done as well I guess ;)

Comment: I was about to suggest doing the same thing with MSE (could be useful), only to see that @ShadowWizard said it already. ( ***and** linked to related feature request* )

Comment: @Shokhet It's a different proposal for the same goal. SE staff will have to pick one. (Or neither, but they're not going to do *that*...)